# Show that infinite power series and function are equal

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Consider the series
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n\left(1-3^{-n}\right) x^{2 n}, \quad|x|<R$$

Show that
$$f(x)=\frac{x^{2}}{\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{2}}-\frac{3 x^{2}}{\left(3-x^{2}\right)^{2}}, \quad|x|<R$$

---

How do I show this? I assume I should exploit that the series is a power series, and thus it must be $f(x)$'s taylor series? But I have no idea how to show that. It isn't exactly easy to find an expression for the $n$th derivative of $f(x)$?

Comment: What do you mean $|x| < R$? Other than that, distribute the parenthesis and you will get two sums. One is a simple geometric series. The other is just the derivative of a "similar" geometric series. I assume you meant $|x|<1$?

Comment: @PopularPower Yes you're right. R is meant the radius of convergence, which in this case is R=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n\left(1-3^{-n}\right) x^{2 n}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\left(x^2\right)^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\left(\frac{x^2}{3}\right)^n\\
&=\frac x2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(2x)\left(x^2\right)^{n-1}-
\frac{x}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\left(\frac{2x}3\right)\left(\frac{x^2}{3}\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\frac x2\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(x^2\right)^n\right)'-
\frac x2\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x^2}3\right)^n\right)'
\end{align}$$ where the primes indicate differentiation with respect to $x$. Now you just have to plug in the values of the geometric series and differentiate.

Comment: I really can't see where you're going. Am I supposed to be able to evaluate the two sums? I don't think it's possible to treat them as a geometric series because of the n being multiplied.

Comment: @mhj  A power series can be differentiated term-by-term.  Think about the derivative of a geometric series.

Comment: I don't follow. But what does the derivative of the power series has to do with f(x)?

Comment: You are supposed to evaluate the power series.  It will turn out to be equal to $f$.

Comment: But how do I evaluate it? It's not an geometric series? I mean it's not on the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ar^n$ but it's $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}anr^n$ ?

Comment: I do see you have written: $\frac{x}{2} \frac{d}{dx} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(x^{2}\right)^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x^{2}}{3}\right)^{n} \right) =  \frac x2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(2x)\left(x^2\right)^{n-1}-
\frac{x}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\left(\frac{2x}3\right)\left(\frac{x^2}{3}\right)^{n-1}$

So you want me to evaluate those sums, and then differentiate?

Comment: Oh thank you. That's smart. How could you just see that was the way to go straight away? I would never figure that out by myself.

Comment: @mhj It's just experience.  I've seen this trick many times before.  You'll get there.